# padrino route with two names

Tags: ruby, padrino

I am thinking about 2 language concepts in my project. I have data separated in database. But I want to have 2 language routes and I don't want to write all routes duplicates.

I have urls

```
mydomain.com/kategorie
mydomain.com/category
```

Is it possible to handle this in one padrino route? I have language setting in cookie, and then is generated language specific content.

It will be better than two routes for "kategorie" and "category".

Comment: probably something along these line [Padrino Localization](http://padrinorb.com/guides/features/localization/) then `get "/#{I18n.t('category')"` if I had to guess

Comment: thanks I will think about this way